# How to make images inline

Tags: javascript, css, dropzone.js

Dropzone.js is not showing preview as one image after another how to resolve this and how to show image with progress bar (not the file name and file size).

I have included `basic.css` file

my code is

in html

```
<div id="dropzone-previews">
</div>
```

javascript

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            paramName: "file",
            maxFilesize: 10,
            url: 'UploadImages',
            previewsContainer: "#dropzone-previews",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 5,
            maxFiles: 20,
            // addRemoveLinks: true,
            init: function() {
                var cd;
                this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                    $('.dz-progress').hide();
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(file);
                    cd = response;
                });
   };
```

[image]

Edit:
      I copied my code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/z0ztuzfh/)** I am selection images from bootstreap model and images are shown at `<div id="dropzone-previews"></div>` which is behind the model.
I have included the code but it is not showing problem which i am fetching at my local host.

Comment: Could you provide us the resulting code (source code from the rendered page) and the css ?

Comment: i assume there is a div starting from name of file beaches-82a.jp to icons tick and cross, you need to set it display:inline-block.
Rendered html will be great for helping you out

Comment: @AliUmair that is not working please see updated question

Comment: it's not the rendered HTML, please viewsource of your page and put particular html and css in fiddle, the code in your fiddle is most probably the html of form of your page. not the produced html of these 3 images